# Eliminate SQL injection possibility while filtering DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF form with with data from SQL database. I get data from SQL, insert it into DataTable and then pass it to WPF DataGrid. I have added several TextBoxes for filtering purposes.

I am getting Table:

```
    public Task<DataView> LoadMainTableDataAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            MainProcess.MergedTable();

            return MainProcess.Customers.DefaultView;
        });
    }
```

Displaying table in DataGrid:

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = await LoadMainTableDataAsync();
```

Here is my current code:

```
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _conditions = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public void FilterSetup()
    {
        try
        {
            string qry = null;
            _conditions["name"] = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessIDSearch.Text))
            {
                qry = string.Format("LY Like '{0}%'", BusinessIDSearch.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameSearch.Text))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
                    qry += " AND ";
                qry += string.Format("HAKUNIMI Like '%{0}%'", NameSearch.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupSearch.Text))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
                    qry += " AND ";
                qry += string.Format("KONSERNI Like '{0}%'", GroupSearch.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IDSearch.Text))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
                    qry += " AND ";
                qry += string.Format("YRNRO Like '{0}%'", IDSearch.Text);
            }

            _conditions["name"] = qry;
            UpdateFilter();
            LiinosFICount.Content = DataGrid1.Items.Count;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I use it like this in TextBox:

```
    private void BusinessIDSearch_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        FilterSetup();
    }
```

My main concern is possibility of SQL injection in this setup?

However I am also facing another issue, while typing to TextBoxes filtering works fine, but while deleting the text I have noticed that I have to delete 3 characters before my data gets updated in DataGrid. So in case of "America", I have press 3 times backspace before my DataGrid is updated, so only when I see "Amer" DataGrid data is updated. Why so?

---

**EDIT:**

Updatefilter method:

```
    private void UpdateFilter()
    {
        try
        {
            var activeConditions = _conditions.Where(c => c.Value != null).Select(c => "(" + c.Value + ")");
            DataView dv = DataGrid1.ItemsSource as DataView;
            dv.RowFilter = string.Join(" AND ", activeConditions);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

```
    public void FilterSetup()
    {

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        _conditions["name"] = null;

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessIDSearch.Text))
            {
                sb.Append("LY Like '%' + @BusinessIDSearch + '%'");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("BusinessIDSearch", BusinessIDSearch.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameSearch.Text))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
                    sb.Append(" AND ");
                sb.Append("HAKUNIMI Like '%' + @NameSearch + '%'");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NameSearch", NameSearch.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupSearch.Text))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
                    sb.Append(" AND ");
                sb.Append("KONSERNI Like '%' + @GroupSearch + '%'");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("GroupSearch", GroupSearch.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IDSearch.Text))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString()))
                    sb.Append(" AND ");
                sb.Append("YRNRO Like '%' + @IDSearch + '%'");
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDSearch", IDSearch.Text);
            }

            //command.CommandText = sb.ToString();

            _conditions["name"] = sb.ToString();

            UpdateFilter();
        }
```

Comment: question: are **parameterised statements** not an option? and if so: why? because those are a very quick, easy and surefire way to protect your database.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I am aware of this approach (not that professional yet, still learning). I remember using parameterized statements while getting data from database. However I am not sure how it should be done while filtering data in DataGrid. Also is it even the right way what I am doing? I also know about MVVM, but it is my next step in learning WPF.

Comment: Please show us your UpdateFilter method.

Comment: @LajosArpad I have added it to my question

Comment: Is for instance YRNRO a field of your ```c```?

Comment: @LajosArpad it is a "column name" of datatable in database. My original query for getting data from database `select YRNRO,HAKUNIMI,KONSERNI,LY from COMPANY`

Comment: If that column name would be mapped, then you could do something like ```c.YRNRO.Contains(yoursearchstring)``` which would be safer.

Comment: question: are you actually issuing any SQL calls here? or is this entirely in-memory; it changes things a lot

Comment: @MarcGravell I am loading data from 2 Database Datatables to C# DataTable. Then I am joining them together into `IEnumerable<JoinedFIandSE>`. After that I am displaying C# DataTable in DataGrid. Currently my question is about filtering C# DataTable while viewing it in DataGrid. I was also thinking that in this setup SQL injection is not possible or is it? I just got suggestion to make it more safe so I have started to investigate how?

Comment: well, it can't be SQL injection if you aren't issuing SQL... it *might* be possible to query more than you expected in the filter, but: they certainly can't do anything more malicious than that. Gotta say, though: loading things into a `DataTable` is rarely the right option.

Comment: @MarcGravell that what I was wondering as well how somebody can actually get through DataTable to SQL. However just for sake of interest, maybe you can add an answer with correct solution for parameterized command based on my latest attempt (EDIT 2). There seems to be some issue as it is not functioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My main concern is possibility of SQL injection in this setup?

You can build the query string itself dynamically as long as you use parameter placeholder instead of inserting the actual value from the `TextBox` into the string. You should also use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
...
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameSearch.Text))
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
        sb.Append(" AND ");
    sb.Append("HAKUNIMI Like '%' + @NameSearch + '%'");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("NameSearch", NameSearch.Text);
}
...
command.CommandText = sb.ToString():
```

Refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077) for more information and a complete example of how to use parameters in a SQL query.

Regarding your other issue, the `TextChanged` event should be fired on each keystroke.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have hard times getting it to work, please see my "EDIT 2" in original question. I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Also am I assigning `sb` to `_conditions["name"]` in a correct way?